# Jenkins multi branch pipeline configuration for bitbucket

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkinsfile

How to configure multi branch  pipeline job for bitbucket ....i have to clone from different branches and build the jobs.... I  found multi branch is the option... How to configure for bit bucket

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gXXwCki94ys

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the [BitBucket Branch Source Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Bitbucket+Branch+Source+Plugin) when using BitBucket. Documentation can be found [here](https://go.cloudbees.com/docs/plugins/bitbucket/)

Answer (score 0):

You could watch this video about multi branch: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gXXwCki94ys

Basically it is about:

- create new item
- choose multibranch
- copy and paste the git url of the project
- choose a ssh key that has been added to the credentials settings
- choose a polling interval of e.g. 1 min in the "scan multibranch pipeline triggers" section